# How to interpolate zero cells in a large excel sheet?

Tags: excel

I have a long excel file which contains numbers collected from a website. Less than 1% of the cells contain zero due to an error from the source. Therefore, I want to find update those cells and interpolate them with the nearest values. The length of the zero cells is some time single, hence I can simply take the average of the nearest non-zero values. However, a few places it is longer than one, hence I need to use linear interpolation.

Sample extracted data

```
+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|   |  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |  E   |  F   |  G   |  H   | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P |  Q   |  R   |  S   |  T   |  U   |  V   |  W   |  X   |  Y   |
+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1 | 4058 | 4048 | 4049 | 4082 | 4090 | 4115 | 4118 | 4109 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3990 | 4058 | 4064 | 4053 | 4057 | 4093 | 4123 | 4137 | 4133 |
+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: I would probably use VBA for this.

Comment: I imported data into matlab, convert zeros as NaN, then simply use fillmissing() function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very general script that might do something like that. It is only tested on positive values and ten rows, so you will definitely need to adapt it to many corner cases - but it should point you in the right direction:

```
Sub Interpolate()
    Dim valueToTop As Integer

    For Row = 1 To 10
        valueToTop = -1
        valueToBottom = -1

        If Cells(Row, 1).Value = 0 Then
            RowToTop = Row - 1
            Do While RowToTop > 0
                If Cells(RowToTop, 1).Value > 0 Then
                    valueToTop = Cells(RowToTop, 1)
                    Exit Do
                End If
                RowToTop = RowToTop - 1
            Loop
            Debug.Print valueToTop
            Debug.Print RowToTop


            RowToBottom = Row + 1
            Do While RowToBottom > 0
                If Cells(RowToBottom, 1).Value > 0 Then
                    valueToBottom = Cells(RowToBottom, 1)
                    Exit Do
                End If
                RowToBottom = RowToBottom + 1
            Loop
            Debug.Print valueToBottom
            Debug.Print RowToBottom

            Cells(Row, 2).Value = valueToTop + (Row - RowToTop) * (valueToBottom - valueToTop) / (RowToBottom - RowToTop)


        End If



    Next Row
End Sub
```